# Seaborn heatmap with 48 variables

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset for which I have filtered down my the possible attributes to be used for model building , they are still coming out to be 48 variables. When I try to draw a corelation map using seaborn heatmap , the values are overwritten and not clear.[image]

Code used

```
    cor = train[cols].corr()
    #fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.heatmap(cor,annot=True)
    plt.show()
```

How can I make this readable ,have tried figsize but still not working. I am using Pycharm

Comment: You need a larger figure, or a smaller fontsize. What exactly did you try that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the fontsize of the annotation by passing `annot_kws` to the function:

```
sns.heatmap(np.arange(100).reshape(10,10), annot=True)
```

[image]

```
sns.heatmap(np.arange(100).reshape(10,10), annot=True, annot_kws={'fontsize':5})
```

[image]